# ruby dynamic class instance creation

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm programming a board game as part of an Ruby OOP learning exercise. I'm attempting to create a game board consisting of nine spaces arranged in three rows of three. Below is a snippet of the currently non-functioning code:

```
class Board

  def initialize()
    #dynamically creates instances of the Space class named @s1 through @s9 with #s 1-9 as the location parameter
    9.times do |x|
      x += 1
      y = "@s" + x.to_s
      instance_variable_set( y , x.to_s) = Space.new
    end
  end

  def print_board
    #prints a 3X3 grid containing each instance's location parameter
    puts "\n\n#{@s1.location}|#{@s2.location}|#{@s3.location}\n-----\n#{@s4.location}|#{@s5.location}|#{@s6.location}\n-----\n#{@s7.location}|#{@s8.location}|#{@s9.location}\n\n\n"
  end
end

class Space

  attr_accessor :location

  def initialize(location)
    @location = location
  end

end

board = Board.new
board.print_board
```

The desired output is:

```
X|X|X
-----
X|X|X
-----
X|X|X
```

...but I keep getting errors related to the creation of instances of the Space class. I've tried so many different things that I can't remember them all. I know there has to be a way to do it like this, but I'm new to Ruby, and it has me stumped. I know could just create 9 individual instances of the Space class, but that seems cheap and dirty.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `instance_variable_set(y , Space.new(x.to_s))`?

Comment: ...Aaaaaand circle gets the square... That was it. I was so close! How do I mark that as the solution?

Comment: You really don't want to set individual variables for each cell. It's much, much better to have a singular instance variable that is an Array or Hash.

Comment: Why is that exactly (I'm new to the party)? The exercise is creating a tic-tac-toe game, and while that's easily done procedurally (not that using an array/hash makes anything procedural), the goal of the exercise is to learn OOP, so I'm trying to maximize my use/grasp/understanding of objects and related things through practice.

Comment: @spectre6000 arrays are designed for accessing objects by an index (e.g. 1..9). Putting the indices in the variable names and using `instance_variable_set` has the same effect, but it's really hacky and could cause lots of unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly re-worked, more Ruby-style version of same:

```
class Board
  def initialize
    @board = Array.new(9) do
      Space.new
    end
  end

  def move(x,y,set)
    @board[(x - 1) + (y - 1) * 3].location = set
  end

  def to_s
    @board.each_slice(3).collect do |row|
      row.join('|')
    end.join("\n------\n") + "\n"
  end
end

class Space
  attr_accessor :location

  def initialize(location = nil)
    @location = location || ' '
  end

  def to_s
    @location
  end
end

board = Board.new
puts board.to_s

board.move(1,2,'x')
puts board.to_s
```

It's worth noting a few tricks:

- `Array.new` takes an argument as to how many entries to pre-populate with.
- An Array can be given a block to evaluate that supplies the value to be used for default entries.
- `each_slice` pulls out groups of *N* entries to process.
- `collect` transforms each row into a simple string.
- `join` combines the rows with horizontal lines.
- `to_s` is the default name for "show as string" and should be used unless it's otherwise confusing.
- `Space` needed a default of `nil` for the initializer
- Methods that do not take arguments do not need brackets, so `initializer` is preferable to `initializer()`.

The approach you're pursuing with `instance_variable_set` is a lot harder to maintain and violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) by having *nine* variables that represent the cells. What you need is one variable of theoretically infinite size, bounded only by constraints you impose if necessary. Having multiple variables makes things much more difficult to iterate, makes it inconvenient to pass through as an argument, and generally makes a mess of what should be simple.